# Looker Alert Issue

Tags: looker

I am new to Looker and trying to create my first alert. The requirement is simple when a status field (calculated field) is greater than 1 looker should send an email. Though a couple of records value is more than 1 still not sending an alert. I didn’t schedule a delivery, just created an alert.

FYI: Row count exceeds 5000

I wanted the Looker to check every 15 min if the calculated field is greater than 1.

attached is the Snap of the alert

[image]

Can anyone please help me with what needs to be done?

TIA

Comment: Firstly I would check these two things:
1. Check whether the Alert is created successfully or not
2. Check whether you have the right permissions to view the alerts or not

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks correct. Check your permission and do a test run before scheduling the email.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).